# How would I get RabbitMQ to work inside of Kubernetes with Traefik?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, rabbitmq, traefik-ingress

I succeeded in getting RabbitMQ to work inside of Kubernetes thanks to this [RabbitMQ/Kubernetes tutorial from Medium](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/deploying-rabbitmq-on-kubernetes-using-rabbitmq-cluster-operator-ef99f7a4e417). And I have already setup traefik similar to [this Traefik tutorial from Medium](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/deploying-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster-b03a0672ae0c).

The problem is that RabbitMQ is only accessible from the outside and not from inside the cluster. I use C# to access RabbitMQ through [this hello world tutorial from RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html). But the part where I have to enter the url only works outside of the cluster.
The `var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };`part is what is restricting me. Because in the next line `using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())` a

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException

gets thrown. Because the url doesn't work inside of a cluster.

To solve this I would probably have to add RabbitMQ in some way to my traefik solution. That way I could define a path which I could use as the url. The problem is that I don't know how to add RabbitMQ into Traefik since it doesn't only use HTTP. Or perhaps there is even a better way to access RabbitMQ from inside a cluster?

Thank you for your time!